# Is $M_{2}(K)$ a polynomial identity ring?

Tags: ring-theory

Simply, if there is a polynomial $f$, in noncommuting variables, which vanishes under substitutions from ring $R$, the ring will be called a PI ring ([Polynomial Identity ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_ring)). For example, commutative rings always satisfy the polynomial $f(x,y) = xy - yx$.

Is $M_{2}(K)$, the ring of all $2 \times2$ matrices over a field $K$, a PI ring? I have tried to construct a polynomial, assuming that this ring is a PI ring, but couldn't find any. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Amitsur-Levitzki theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitsur%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem).

Any four $2\times 2$ matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ satisfy 
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_4} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)A_{\sigma(1)}A_{\sigma(2)}A_{\sigma(3)}A_{\sigma(4)}=0.$$
Hence $M_2(K)$ satisfies the polynomial identity
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_4} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}x_{\sigma(3)}x_{\sigma(4)}$$
of degree $4$ in four variables. This generalizes to $M_{n}(K)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Is there any restrictions on the degree of this polynomial? I mean, when you gave above polynomial of degree 4, so I shouldn't expect to find any of degree 3.

Comment: @Arturo, I got my last question's answer. It will satisfy a polynomial of degree exactly 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Besides to first pervasive answer, suppose $A$ and $B$ be such two matrices. The **Cayley–Hamilton theorem** implies that if $x$= $(AB-BA)$ then $(AB-BA)^2$ commutes with any other $2\times 2$ matrix in $M_{2}(K)$. It leads you to $f(x,y,z)=(xy-yx)^2z-z(xy-yx)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Matrix rings over a given commutative ring (in particular, over any field) are indeed PI, and in some sense are the motivating prototypes.

Since you say this is homework, I am reluctant to give an explicit reference for this fact, at least until you give some more context. Were you given any hints in the course? Is this an optional question for interest, or are you expected to work out the answer using things mentioned in class?

Comment: Thanks for hints. I expected to examine and find this ploynomial for the given statement in the class.